# Jar file won't execute, not sure if I'm creating it correctly

Tags: java, windows, jar

I'm trying to make a jar file out of two classes, one of which depends on an external jar. I have a directory with a manifest.txt, a lib folder containing the external jar RXTXcomm.jar, and a folder named Arduino containing my two classes, SendValue.java and SerialClass.java.

First I'm compiling my classes using:

```
javac arduino\*.java
```

This creates 3 new files, SerialClass$1.class, SerialClass.class and SendValue.class. To make the jar file, I'm running:

```
jar -cfm send.jar manifest.txt arduino\*.class lib\rxtxcomm.jar
```

This works fine. I then try to run the file using:

```
java send.jar
```

I get the error:

```
Could not find or load main class send.jar
```

I've also tried to run it with the following command, and got the same error:

```
java -cp . send.jar
```

The only line in my manifest.txt is :

```
Main-Class: Arduino.SendValue
```

My classes run fine in Eclipse, so I'm assuming they're not the problem. SendValue.java has the line:

```
public static void main(String[] ag) {
```

as it's supposed to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run your `jar` using:

```
java -jar send.jar
```

Also, unless you want to do some magic with nested jars with some tool like [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=quickstart), you should remove `lib\rxtxcomm.jar` from your `jar` command, and add the following line to your manifest.

```
Class-Path: lib\rxtxcomm.jar .
```

Comment: Running it that way threw up a different error: no main manifest attribute, in send.jar. I tried making the jar file the way you suggested, but running it even with the -jar option gave the same error I was getting at first.

Comment: I just realised I missed the period at the end of that line. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the command line or terminal for running a single java executable, then use

```
java -jar send.jar
```

Also it would be better if you went through compiling and testing using an IDE such as Netbeans, IntelliJ IDEA, or Eclipse as they're meant to do such stuff and are more reliable on doing the steps unlike the human brain.

Comment: Thanks, but this is throwing up the error: no main manifest attribute, in send.jar. I tried to compile through eclipse and I'm getting the same error trying to run it this way.